# Image animation not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation

I have 2 images on top of each other.
When the top one moves to a different spot, both of them become kind of distorted/blurry. After a second, the images return to normal.

How do I stop this from happening?

http://jsfiddle.net/jenga/W59c4/

Comment: What browser are you using? Works fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: I see what you mean in Chrome V21.0.1180.83

Comment: Hm. I think was using Chrome 21 before. I just tried ie and it worked fine. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has an actual size of 140 x 198. You are shrinking and expanding it to a different size. Because of the way raster images work, this causes blurriness and/or distortion. Use a bigger source image, higher DPI, or don't expand it beyond the base size of your source image.

Otherwise, the perceived "smoothness" of any javascript animation is very dependent on the client computer's resources. If your browser thread is running high on memory (Firefox+Firebug can balloon up to 1gb of resident RAM consumption after a few hours of work!), or if your system doesn't have a lot of available resource to start with, animations can be jerky and screen rendering can be slow or glitchy.

Other than the distortion caused by the scaling, your animation runs smoothly on my own computer (I have a lot of resources to work with :P)

**Documentation**

- *Raster Graphics* on Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics

Answer (score 0):

Resize the black card down to the desired dimensions. You're working with an original that's 600px wide and shrinking it to 75px wide; that's the cause of the distortion.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the browser doesn't anti-alias the black card because it's not in view. During the animation the browser is rapidly updating position and scale of the blue card. As a performance measure, anti-aliasing might be put off until there's room for the browser to breath beyond what the tight setTimeout looping provides.